# Ionic Header with Title and 2 Buttons on right side

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to build my app and I have a modal view that pops up and am trying to have a `HEADER TITLE` and then have 2 buttons on the right of the `TITLE` but when I try to do this it always puts one of the buttons on the left. I Here is the main code snippet:

```
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button side="right" class="button">Left Button</button>
      </div>
   </ion-header-bar>
```

Full code available [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWdGBX).

Comment: @Darth_Vader just cause you cant understand it dosent mean it should be downvoted clearly it made sense to others and is why it got a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because Ionic selects the `buttons` class following this rule:

```
.bar .title + .buttons { ... }
```

That means, that these styles **only** apply to the element of class `buttons`, that's directly following the element with class `title`! See [more information about the plus selector on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Just put the two buttons together in the `div` wrapper to avoid this behaviour:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  <button class="button">Left Button</button>
</div>
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>Ionic Template</title>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
        <button class="button">Left Button</button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
  </ion-modal-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I am just wondering why the second div in my code is put on the left side even though it comes after in the HTML? Has Ionic done something in the css so that happens?